# How to combine Google login with Azure AD login in an azure app?

Tags: azure, gmail, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a Web App and published a simple MVC application. In the Azure Portal I have configured two identity providers: Azure AD and Google. When I visit my site, I am presented a login screen, which is perfect.

However, I can only choose to use or Azure Ad or Google as the Identity Provider. What I want is a combination. When I go to my URL, I want to have the possibilty that the visitor can choose to login with his gmail or with a azure ad account.

How can I do this? And is this even possible?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.. "However, I can only choose to use or Azure Ad or Google as the Identity Provider."  

Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, in the Azure Portal I can only choose one of those. I cannot choose to use a combination. On my Web App I would like to have the option to choose to login with Google or with Azure AD

Comment: I know this can be achieved programmatically using the Owin Nuget Libraries and add both providers (Google and OpenIdConnect) inside if your owin startup.cs class.  I'm not sure if there is a way to do it through the portal.  You will also need to write a custom login page and let the user select their provider before proceeding with authentication.  Here are the samples that I've used to help me: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-code-samples/

Comment: Do you choose them by just removing one at all from Identity Providers list or do you choose them by using policies?

Comment: That seems silly. Why would they have the option to add multiple identity providers. And then limit you to only use 1. Lets also clarify if we talking azure ad B2C or B2B.